# A movie with jumping into another world and being served dinosaur for dinner

Tags: story-identification, movie

A movie where a group of people teleports to a deserted place through a ring-shaped machine. They enter from one side of the machine and it takes them like they're going through space, and just jumps out to a deserted place. They find people with some creatures, and in one scene the people of that place have them for the campfire where a dinosaur is provided as the dinner. A guy from the group eats it, shows symbols that it tasted like chicken, and then another person from the same group translates it for the people of that place.

I think I watched it around 2002-2005. Not sure though.

But the thing I remember the most is the one mentioned above saying they bring dinosaurs for dinner in a campfire.

Comment: Are you sure it was a film? Sliders had dinosaurs too http://www.everythingaction.com/2011/10/08/total-recall-sliders-dinoslide/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Stargate* (1994)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_(film)). Archeologist Daniel Jackson is presented some mystery meat/creature, everyone else declines he takes a bite and declares that it tastes like chicken (a popular trope).

[image: two characters sitting at a table]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Isq7rLds8wQ lol. Director's cut of that scene

Comment: Thank God. Thats the one. :)